# possible to make some output in do notation and then return a String in haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

is it possible in haskell, to make some operations live output and then return a string with a function like:

```
test :: String -> String
test x = do
    putStrLn x
    -- make some stuff
    return "abc"
```

Comment: No - you can't *run* an IO computation so `test` will always need the type `test :: String -> IO String` instead. Other monads (State, Reader, Writer...) have a run function so they would allow you to do something similar, though obviously as they are different monads you couldn't have `putStrLn` within the body of the do.

Comment: mathepic: Because IO is restricted in Haskell. As everything is pure (immutable), you can't just change something or print something out. Becuase of this reason, you have to explicitly point out, where you want to do IO. This is the reason why there is the IO monad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. But then, your function `test` must be an `IO` function too. So you have to write `test :: String -> IO String` as it's type instead. Also, the usage is different then. You have to „Unwrap“ the value first:

```
 -- instead of
 if (test string == "abc") then ...
 -- you have to write
 do string' <- test string -- unwrap
    if (string' == "abc") then ...
```

I can understand, that there is sometimes the need to print a debug message somewhere deep inside a pure computation. For this special usecase, there is the function `trace` from `Debug.Trace`. It has the type `trace :: String -> a -> a`, it prints out it's first argument and then returns it second. This is often useful, if you write a complicated program and want to verify it works. But beware: You cannot predict when the message is printed or whether it is printed. It may appear once twice or not at all, depending on the compilers mood.